# Validating Data for an Existing Record in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have encountered an issue on which I haven't found much documentation online. I'm hopeful the SO community will have some advice.

I am currently trying to build a Profile Update page, which doesn't require that all of the fields are to be required. In other words, I'm hoping to set rules with *$this->form_validation->set_rules()* for all fields, but understanding that only a few fields will be populated and sent. The idea being that, if a field has been modified, then it is assumed to be updated.

How can I achieve this?

Edit 1: Trying to allow a user to update their profile. The profile already exists, but they might not submit all fields when updating so the ones that are "required" would reject, no?

No code - I'm asking how to even approach the conundrum. Thanks!

Thanks!

-E

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Post your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Compare sended values and database values before updating. Do not update if they are all same.